# How can I achieve this URI scheme in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm making a blog site with CodeIgniter, and I'd like to use the first URI segment as a dynamic category.

So all of these URI's:
http://example.com/category1/some-post
http://example.com/category2/some-post
http://example.com/category3/some-post

Would all go to the "categories" controller, where it would find the category from the database.

I can achieve this easily enough with `$routes['(:any)'] = 'categories';` , but of course then all of my other static controllers wouldn't work, such as admin, user, etc.

So how can I achieve this URI scheme while allowing other static pages to not be routed?

Answer (score 0):

You can't unless you create specific routes for each category manually.

For instance:

```
$route['php'] = 'categories';
$route['java'] = 'categories';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at wordpress they start categories with `/category/` and all pages are anything else so you should probably do it that way round.

Answer (score 0):

You will, as Francois said, have to create a route for each category.  This can be slightly simplified with a simple array as below:

```
$categories = array('cat1','cat2','etc...');

foreach($categories as $cat)
{
    $routes["$cat/(:any)"] = "category/$cat/\$1"
}
```

A possible alternative is to use a pre-controller hook in which you could query your database to see if the segment is a category and then direct the request appropriately.

If you'll have a lot of categories or they will be added to and updated frequently, I'd recommend the second option, otherwise, maintaining a simple array isn't too bad.

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to declare all your static controllers in your routes...